# Foundational sufficient statistics

Tags: self-study, mathematical-statistics, notation, sufficient-statistics, subset

I've been reading through Casella and Berger's *Statistical Infererence* and have am having a little trouble understanding something in their explanation of sufficient statistics. Here is the passage from page 272-273 before I proceed (note that $\boldsymbol X= (X_1,X_2,...,X_n)$):

[image: Sufficent passage]

It could be that I'm overworked, but it has not been too clear to me why $\{\boldsymbol X=\boldsymbol x\},\{ \boldsymbol Y= \boldsymbol x\} \subseteq \{T(\boldsymbol X)=T(\boldsymbol x)\}$. Is it the case that
$$\{T(\boldsymbol X)=T(\boldsymbol x)\}=\{\boldsymbol X: T(\boldsymbol X)=T(\boldsymbol x)\}???$$
I was hoping someone could help clear this up for me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's just a matter of understanding the notation.

#### Preliminaries

A random variable, such as $\boldsymbol X$, is [a measurable function on a probability space](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/50/what-is-meant-by-a-random-variable/54894#54894),

$$\boldsymbol X: \Omega \to \mathbb{R}^n.$$

A statistic $T$ is a measurable function

$$T: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}.$$

The composite function

$$T\circ \boldsymbol{X}:\Omega \to \mathbb{R};\ T(\boldsymbol{X})(\omega) = T(\boldsymbol{X}(\omega))$$

is therefore also a random variable.

Let $\boldsymbol{x}\in\mathbb{R}^n$: it is a possible value of $\boldsymbol X$. Therefore $t = T(\boldsymbol{x})\in \mathbb R$ is a possible value of the statistic $T$.

#### Notation

The set-building notation used in this context is a shorthand--some would say an abuse of--the more explicit mathematical notation

$$\{T(\boldsymbol X) = T(\boldsymbol x)\} = \{\omega\in\Omega\,|\,T(\boldsymbol{X}(\omega)) = T(\boldsymbol{x})\}= \{\omega\in\Omega\,|\,T(\boldsymbol{X}(\omega)) = t\}.$$

Let's call this set $\mathcal T$.  The mathematical notation clearly exhibits $\mathcal T$ as a subset of $\Omega$ and, because $T\circ \boldsymbol X$ is measurable, it is an event.  It is the set of all outcomes where the value of $T\circ\boldsymbol{X}$ equals a given value of the statistic $T$, namely $T(\boldsymbol{x}) = t$.  In other words, $\mathcal T$ consists of all outcomes where the statistic $T$ has the value $t$.

Similarly, the other set-building notations used in the quotation should be interpreted as

$$\boldsymbol{X}^{*}(\boldsymbol{x}) = \{\boldsymbol{X} = \boldsymbol{x}\} = \{\omega\in\Omega\,|\,\boldsymbol{X}(\omega) = \boldsymbol{x}\}$$

$$\boldsymbol{Y}^{*}(\boldsymbol{x}) =\{\boldsymbol{Y} = \boldsymbol{x}\} = \{\omega\in\Omega\,|\,\boldsymbol{Y}(\omega) = \boldsymbol{x}\}.$$

Both of these are events: $\boldsymbol{X}^{*}(\boldsymbol{x})$ is the event where the value of $\boldsymbol X$ is $\boldsymbol x$ and $\boldsymbol{Y}^{*}(\boldsymbol{x})$ is the event where the value of $\boldsymbol Y$ is $\boldsymbol x$.  They needn't be the same event, because $X$ and $Y$ are not necessarily the same random variable.

#### Solution

By construction, if we apply $T\circ \boldsymbol{X}$ to any element $\omega$ of *either* of these sets, we will obtain the value $T(\boldsymbol{x}) = t$, which by definition means $\omega\in\mathcal T$.  We have merely observed that

$$\boldsymbol{X}(\omega) = \boldsymbol{x} \implies T(\boldsymbol{X}(\omega)) = t$$

and

$$\boldsymbol{Y}(\omega) = \boldsymbol{x} \implies T(\boldsymbol{Y}(\omega)) = t,$$

immediately proving that

$$\boldsymbol{X}^{*}(\boldsymbol{x}) \subset \mathcal T$$

and

$$\boldsymbol{Y}^{*}(\boldsymbol{x}) \subset \mathcal T,$$

*QED*.

Comment: This was incredibly concise, whuber. I understand fully now. Thank you so much! Once I get to +15 reputation, expect an up-vote.